# Is there a function in MATLAB that will estimate the initial condition from a set of data?

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

I was given a state-space model of a system and a list of outputs for t=0 to t=5, sampled every 0.1 seconds and asked to approximate the initial condition. Is there a function in MATLAB that will take a long list of data and approximate the initial condition of the system?

The system
$$\dot x=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 & 0\\0 & -1 & -1\\1 & 0 & -2\end{bmatrix}x + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}u$$

$$y = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}x$$

was given the input $u(t) = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ for $t = 0$ to $5$ seconds and the following data was obtained by sampling every 0.1 seconds. 
Approximately what was the initial condition $x(0)$?

$$\begin{array}{c|l}
t & \text{y(t)}\\
\hline
0.0 & 0.0000\\
0.1 & 0.556011\\
0.2 & 1.02816\\
0.3 & 1.42273\\
0.4 & 1.74606\\
0.5 & 2.00443\\
0.6 & 2.20402\\
0.7 & 2.35082\\
0.8 & 2.45059\\
0.9 & 2.50882\\
1.0 & 2.5307\\
1.1 & 2.52112\\
1.2 & 2.48461\\
1.3 & 2.4254\\
1.4 & 2.34736\\
1.5 & 2.25403\\
1.6 & 2.14863\\
1.7 & 2.03404\\
1.8 & 1.91286\\
1.9 & 1.78739\\
2.0 & 1.65964\\
2.1 & 1.53138\\
2.2 & 1.40411\\
2.3 & 1.27914\\
2.4 & 1.15753\\
2.5 & 1.04019\\
2.6 & 0.927817\\
2.7 & 0.82098\\
2.8 & 0.720091\\
2.9 & 0.625442\\
3.0 & 0.53721\\
3.1 & 0.455476\\
3.2 & 0.380238\\
3.3 & 0.311418\\
3.4 & 0.248879\\
3.5 & 0.192432\\
3.6 & 0.141847\\
3.7 & 0.0968592\\
3.8 & 0.0571798\\
3.9 & 0.0225006\\
4.0 & -0.00749888\\
4.1 & -0.0331464\\
4.2 & -0.0547719\\
4.3 & -0.0727038\\
4.4 & -0.0872657\\
4.5 & -0.0987728\\
4.6 & -0.10753\\
4.7 & -0.11383\\
4.8 & -0.11795\\
4.9 & -0.120156\\
5.0 & -0.120694\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I'm going to give you a hint, and if I happen to have time tomorrow, I'll describe in more detail. Since $u\equiv 0$, it's not difficult to find an *analytic* formula for $x(t)$ that depends only on the initial condition $x_0$. Once you have that, a formula for $y(t)$ is straighforward. The key is this: for a fixed $t$, $y(t)$ *is a simple linear function of $x_0$. So what you're left with is a system of 51 equations and 3 unknowns---an overdetermined linear system. Construct the coefficients of that linear system and a simple `A\b` will get you the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make this generic: consider the linear system $\dot{x}=Ax+Bu$, $y=Cx+Du$. If $u\equiv 0$ then the specific values of $B,D$ are irrelevant and 
$$x(t)=e^{At}x_0, \quad y(t) = Cx(t) =Ce^{At}x_0$$
where $x_0$ is the initial state. In your case, you have data for
$$t\in\{0,T,2T,\dots,NT\} \qquad T=0.1, \quad N=50$$ 
If we define $\bar{A}\triangleq e^{AT}$ and $y_k\triangleq y(kT)$, then $y_k = CA^kx_0$. Therefore
$$\begin{bmatrix} y_0 \\ y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_N \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} C \\ C\bar{A} \\ C\bar{A}^2 \\ \vdots \\ C\bar{A}^N \end{bmatrix} x_0.$$
Construct this overdetermined $(N+1)\times n$ linear system and solve with a simple backslash operation to find $x_0$. If the measurements are exact and there is no noise in the system, the value of $x_0$ obtained will be exact as well.

In practice, neither the assumption of exact measurements or noise-free operation is valid. Therefore, I'd weight the earlier samples more than the later ones. Assuming no system noise and exact measurements, this would give the same result for any $w_0,w_1,\dots,w_N>0$:
$$\begin{bmatrix} w_0 y_0 \\ w_1 y_1 \\ w_2 y_2 \\ \vdots \\ w_N y_N \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} w_0 C \\ w_1 C\bar{A} \\ w_2 C\bar{A}^2 \\ \vdots \\ w_N C\bar{A}^N \end{bmatrix} x_0.$$
A common choice is $w_k=\alpha^k$ for some forgetting factor $0<\alpha<1$. A more rigorous development would use statistics about the noise and/or measurement errors to come up with proper weighting. Indeed, that's the very kind of rigor you find in Kalman filter theory.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is so thorough, it really helps. I really appreciate you taking the time to write all this out.